# VBA code for merge bunch of CSV file to single worksheet with certain range only

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I need to merge bunch of CSV files in the same folder to a single worksheet. I just need data from `A11` until last column and `D11` until last column. When it pastes in worksheets, it will be at `A` and `B` column.

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I do have a code but it copy everything in csv sheets and stack it in single worksheet. I have to cut so many unneeded data.i will show the cod later

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim DataLine As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SkipLines As Integer
Dim r As Long
Const FileDirectory As String = "C:\Test\"
Const FileMask As String = "*.csv"
Sub LoadCSV()
On Error GoTo errorhandler
Set ws = Sheets.Add
r = 1
FileName = Dir(FileDirectory & FileMask, vbNormal)
While FileName <> ""
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
    For SkipLines = 1 To 10
        If Not EOF(FileNum) Then
            Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        Else
            MsgBox "There must be at least 11 rows of data. Skipping File", vbInformation, FileName
            GoTo skipfile
        End If
    Next SkipLines
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        arrDataLine = Split(DataLine, ",")
        If UBound(arrDataLine) >= 3 Then
            ws.Cells(r, 1) = arrDataLine(0)
            ws.Cells(r, 2) = arrDataLine(3)
            r = r + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "There must be at least 4 columns of data. Skipping File", vbInformation, FileName
            GoTo skipfile
        End If
    Wend
skipfile:
    Close #FileNum
    FileName = Dir$
Wend
GoTo cleanup
errorhandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & "->" & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
cleanup:
Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Neuralgroove..thanks for ur code but nothing happen when i run it.i cant share my code bcause im using mobile.any idea how?im very new in here

Comment: need more detail..make sure you change the FileDirectory path to wherever your files are, then step through the code (F8) to try and see whats going on..you can also comment out the  `On Error GoTo errorhandler` line  to debug